# How do I select from a dictionary whose values are a list of lists in python2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary with key value pairs, as they are. The values are all lists or lists of lists.

For a dictionary that looks like this:

```
    d={}
    d['FM_001323'] = [[45,11232],[300,400],[65,700]]
    d['FM_094326'] = [11500,12500]
```

If I want to see the first entry for each list in the value by each key, I can't just do the below like I could if every entry was a list of lists:

```
    for j in d:
           for i in range(0,len(d[j]):
                  print d[j][i][0]
```

Because the second key in my dictionary only has a single list for a value, not a list of lists, and the [0] index doesn't have any reference. Does that make sense?

I want to isolate the first entry in each list-value for each key. It's easy with either list-values or lists of list-values, but mixing them together complicates it.

I am also open to easier ways to reach the same goal. For context: I am trying to compare the numbers in the values with variables from other parts of this code by that FM_ figure. Any way of isolating these would suffice for me.

Expected output would be

```
    45
    300
    65
    11500
```

Comment: use if type(d[j][i]) == type([]) to check whether the element in list is actually a list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing is `"Asked Forgiveness Not Permission"`

```
d={}
d['FM_001323'] = [[45,11232],[300,400],[65,700]]
d['FM_094326'] = [11500,12500]

for j in d:
    for i in range(0,len(d[j])):
        try:
            print(d[j][i][0])
        except TypeError:
            print(d[j][0])
            break
```

prints:

```
45
300
65
11500
```

Basically just do it in try blocks and catch the exception that will throw if it didn't work out and try it again with something else.

Edited so to OP's desired output. Just break out of the loop after the first print because your second for loop is there to loop through the sub lists right? You don't have a sub list so just break out of it

Comment: This gets me real close, but I don't want to see the 12500 print in this case. If I sub out [i] with [0] in the except statement, it prints 11500 twice, which still isn't quite right.

Comment: @user3240735 Sorry edited to your liking. See if need further editing.

Comment: --Perfect! Thanks! As you can tell, I'm somewhat new to python and didn't even consider the break.

Comment: @user3240735 It's all good, I'm glad to see someone learning.

Comment: This code is correct only if for d[j] = [11500,[1,2],1300], the expected answer is 11500 instead of (11500,1,1300).

Comment: @Shasha99 While that's true, OP never said anything about that data being in OP data source, My answer only reflects on what was provided, and if OP changes the data set, so will my answer. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: Hmm,i tried sorting out this in my solution. Yes Your answer looks correct as per the requirements. + from my side!!!

Comment: Having try:except is all fine, but the given data set will guaranty the exception, and catching the actual exception is huge overhead, and I would recommend not using try:except when data set is all but known will throw that exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
d={}
d['FM_001323'] = [[45,11232],[300,400],[65,700]]
d['FM_094326'] = [11500,12500]
for k in d:
    for v in d[k]:
        if isinstance(v, list): 
            print v[0]    
        else:
            print v
```

Output: 45 300 65 11500 12500

Answer (score 1):

Or cleaner and shorter:

```
d={}
d['FM_001323'] = [[45,11232],[300,400],[65,700]]
d['FM_094326'] = [11500,12500]

for j in d.itervalues():
    for i in j:
        if isinstance(i,list):
            print(i[0])
        else:
            print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Only a single additional line is required in your code. You should have a check on the element type. Something like this:

```
for j in d:
    for i in range(0,len(d[j])):
        #See the line below.
        if type(d[j][i]) == type([]):
           print(d[j][i][0])
        else
            print(d[j][i])
```

**Note:** in case you want to print only the first element when the d[j] only have numbers and no lists. you may have to run an additional loop to find out whether d[j] has any list in it or not. See code below:

```
for j in d:
    #Check if all elements in d[j] are int.
    for i in d[j]:
        if type(i) ==type([]):
            break
    else:
        print(d[j][0])
        continue

    for i in range(0,len(d[j])):
        #See the line below.
        if type(d[j][i]) == type([]):
           print(d[j][i][0])
        else:
            print(d[j][i])
```

So for **d[j] = [11500,[1,2],1300]** , **11500 1** and **1300** would be printed.

Comment: This is real close, but I don't want to see the 12500 print in this case. For the else piece: If I sub out [i] with [0], it prints 11500 twice, which still isn't quite right

Comment: Ok, then what do you want to be printed when d['FM_094326'] = [11500,[1,2,3],12500,12000] ?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clearer. The list of lists will only ever have pairs in the form [[111,444],[222,555],[333,666]] and so forth. Anyway, what I needed was "break" which was delivered to me by MooingRawr up top. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to convert to `str` first and march on `r'\[{0-9}+'`, which would give all leading elements:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import re

d={}
d['FM_001323'] = [[45,11232],[300,400],[65,700]]
d['FM_094326'] = [11500,12500]

for v in d.values():
    print('\n'.join(s[1:] for s in re.findall(r'\[[0-9]+', str(v))))
```